# Report Viewer in WPF

Tags: wpf, crystal-reports, reportviewer, report

I have a WPF project and I need to preview a crystal report. Is it possible to do this?
I can't find a report viewer control in WPF project.

thanks

Comment: What kind of report are you talking about?

Comment: sorry I didn't mention it. It's crystal report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CrystalReportViewer` of windows form with Windows form interop technology to add the viewer to your WPF applicaion.
see [`WindowsFormsHost` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.windowsformshost.aspx)